# Multi Tenancy on DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate with DocuSign. I have a product which has multiple clients. Those clients have multiple users who will use DocuSign.

Is it possible to have one account & then create sub-accounts for different clients & give access to specific users under one account?

I don't want my client to create an account with DocuSign & pay the bills. I would like to pay for all my clients but segregate document, branding etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think Organization Admin may provide the solution for you.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/admin101/
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide